# Deterministic/Non-Deterministic Finite Automata

Tags: computer-science, dfa, nfa

I am new here. I am currently facing some difficulties in understanding the DFAs and NFAs. I have a drawing which I am unable to :

-Differentiate if it's DFA or NFA

-The formal specifications

-How to use the GNFA algorithm to give a regular expression to obtain the maximal marks?

[image: Diagram of DFA/NFA]

I would really appreciate if I could learn and gain some explanation on how to understand this.

Thanks in advance for the time.

Answer (score 0):

DFAs are determinate. NFAs are indeterminate. You can easily see if a state diagram is a DFA or a NFA by looking at it's arrows or transitions.

In a DFA, every type of transition function is documented through the symbols in the alphabet of the language it will accept. Namely, each symbol will have a fixed transition, whereas in an NFA they might have more than one transition or perhaps no transitions for certain symbols.

An NFA has the following properties:

1. Ability to take a step without reading any input symbol
2. A state may have no transition on a particular symbol
3. Ability to transition to more than one state on a given symbol

For your image, assuming that your alphabet are the characters { a, b }, you can see which type is it. Can you see why? There are some states that do not have transitions on certain symbols.

GNFAs are a little bit more complicated. The idea is that they can be converted into regular expressions. You can search online for information about this proof. You can also search for the formal definitions of DFAs and NFAs online.

> Source: my cs theory class, and
>   https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2013/Lectures/lec04.pdf